# Modify theme.liquid using Shopify API

Tags: javascript, python, api, rest, shopify

I am looking to add a `javascript` snippet for some analytics across the store using the [Shopify API](https://docs.shopify.com/api). I figured out that using `admin/themes/:id/assets.json` I can modify the `theme.liquid` to insert snippet but this changes the entire content of the page. The current API call that I do is

```
admin/themes/35073539/assets.json
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "layout\/theme.liquid",
    "value": "{{content_for_header}}<script>console.log('foo')</script>"
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work.

I just want to modify the `<head>` tag and insert some custom `javascript`. Also, `ScriptTag` won't be useful as I have to take some input from user, use that input in my `javascript` and then insert the snippet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

First you want to get a list of all assets to make sure you are using the right ID in the Endpoint URL.  (the long number before /assets.json)

```
GET /admin/themes/#{id}/assets.json
```

Then you want to save a copy of the current file to the server as a backup, just to be safe...

```
PUT /admin/themes/#{id}/assets.json
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "layout\/theme.bak.liquid",
    "source_key": "layout\/theme.liquid"
  }
}
```

Since the method you are using overwrites the existing file,  you need to download the current file, pull the HTML into a javascript variable,  modify that HTML, then send the HTML back as you were doing above.

First download theme.liquid....

```
GET /admin/themes/#{id}/assets.json?asset[key]=layout/theme.liquid&theme_id=828155753
```

This will return the HTML etc.. for that file,  you need to add/change the content of this file and then send that content as you were already ...

```
PUT /admin/themes/#{id}/assets.json
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "layout\/theme.liquid",
    "value": "*****The HTML FOR THEME.LIQUID"
  }
}
```

And that should do it.  If it's successful the code should now be added.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: But if the user installs a new theme, wouldn't the  `theme.liquid` file change?

Comment: I meant to say that if the user installs a new theme, my analytics code would be removed. Is there any way I could put it somewhere where even if the user installs a new theme, it doesn't effect my code?

Comment: But the JSON & ARRAY response displaying data without html tag, So how can I get the code same to same as liquid?

Comment: You'll need to subscribe to [`themes/update`](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook) webhook and update the new theme once it's set as main.